# How to identify latest segments only that started over 6 months post previous segments?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a data set of program eligibilities as follows:

```
ID  PGM     DATE_EFF  DATE_END
1   P1      3/1/2018  4/30/2019
1   P2      1/1/2017  12/31/2017
2   P1      2/1/2018  12/31/2018
2   P2      1/1/2017  5/31/2017
3   P2      4/1/2018  3/31/2019
3   P1      1/1/2017  3/31/2017
3   P3      1/1/2016  12/31/2016
```

So I’m interested with only IDs(and rows) with programs with DATE_EFF (effective dates) between 2/1/2018 and 4/30/2018. Of these IDs and rows, I only return rows of IDs identified that also did not have any other program eligibility within the last 6 months of the “current” eligibility (i.e. "current" means fell between 2/1/2018 and 4/30/2018). So the results would be as follows with the rest omitted:

```
ID  PGM      DATE_EFF  DATE_END
2   P1       2/1/2018  12/31/2018
3   P2       4/1/2018  3/31/2019
```

ID 1 was not returned because though one program started between 2/1/2018 and 4/30/2018 (on 3/1/2018), the ID had another eligibility within the last 6 months of it which ended on 12/31/2017. DATE_EFF and DATE_END are number type. Help?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want something like this:

```
select * from myTable 
where ID not in 
(select ID 
 From myTable 
 where DATE_EFF not between '2018-03-01' and '2018-04-30'
 union
 select ID 
 From myTable 
 where date_end > add_months(sysdate, -6)
```

Comment: this would only get the IDs with segments between the date range but it doesn't check to make sure that the identified ID/segment did not also have another program segment within the past 6 months.

Comment: see my edit, I added a union to the inner query to check the last 6 months

Answer (score 1):

You can try to join your table to itself via an outer join. Try something like the query below:

```
select 
    current.*
from
    my_table current -- values to return
    left outer join my_table eligible -- IDs that were eligible in the past
        on (
                -- Join by ID
                current.id=eligible.id
                -- Only join rows eligible in the past 6 months
                and eligible.date_end > add_months(sysdate, -6) 
            )
where
    -- Get "current" rows
    current.DATE_EFF between TO_DATE('2/1/2018') and TO_DATE('4/30/2018') 
    -- And make sure this ID didn't have any eligible rows
    and eligible.id is null
```